# Append data to JSON element

Tags: jquery, json

I have some JSON data. For example:

```
["Test1","Internet Explorer 4.0","Win 95+","4","X","X"],
["Test2","Internet Explorer 4.0","Win 95+","4","X","Y"]
```

What i want is to add another "value" to each of this elements. For example:

```
["Test1","Internet Explorer 4.0","Win 95+","4","X","X", "NEW1"],
["Test2","Internet Explorer 4.0","Win 95+","4","X","Y", "NEW2"]
```

I tried many things but can't get it to work properly.

`apend()` adds a completely new element therefore that is not working.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: It is a object. I receive it via a AJAX call from my server. Thanks

Comment: What you mean with "relevant object"? This is exactly my question. How can i push the data for each array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Arry.push function to add a new element:

```
var data = [["Test1","Internet Explorer 4.0","Win 95+","4","X","X"],
            ["Test2","Internet Explorer 4.0","Win 95+","4","X","Y"]];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   data[i].push('NEW' + (i + 1));
}
```